# Как передать объект в контроллер asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

В общем, есть метод в контроллере, который принимает в качестве параметра объект типа collection:

```
public IActionResult Index(Collection collection) 
{    
     ItemsIndexViewModel model = new ItemsIndexViewModel();
     model.Items = _itemContext.Items.ToList();
     model.Collection = collection;
     return View(model);
}
```

принятый объект он сохраняет как поле в другой объект, но это не суть.
Есть представление, которое выводит в таблицу все объекты Collection из таблицы в базе данных:

```
@foreach (var collection in Model) {
    if (User.Identity.Name == collection.UserName)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => collection.Id)
            </td>            
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => collection.UserName)
            </td>          
            <td>
                <form action="/Item/Index" method="post" name="сollection">
                    <input type="submit"  value="View all items" />
                </form>

                <a asp-controller="Collection" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@collection.Id">delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

нужно, чтобы при нажатии на input, в контроллер передавался сам объект collection из базы данных, но, на деле, не передается ничего.
При дебаге, метод принимает объект collection, но его значения равны null [image: значения переменных при дебаге]

Comment: Зачем передавать всю коллекцию  на сервер?

Comment: Раньше передавал только id и уже на сервере искал нужную коллекцию, но сказали переделать и передавать всю коллекцию)